# Pass reference to file in asset sub folder

Tags: android, assets

Here is the layout of my android project:

```
src
gen
assets
  MyFolder
       Image1.jpg
       Image2.jpg
  Image3.jpg
bin
libs
res
```

So, what I am trying to do is to pass a string reference of Image1.jpg to the following method ([API](http://beyondar.github.io/beyondar/doxygen/dc/dda/classcom_1_1beyondar_1_1android_1_1world_1_1_beyondar_object.html#af1533d1207a3ac4c16180e91f0b108d9)):

```
void com.beyondar.android.world.BeyondarObject.setImageUri  (   String  uri )
```

So, if I do

```
 go.setImageUri("assets://Image3.jpg");
```

it works, but **how can I pass the string reference of Image1.jpg and Image2.jpg which are under assets/myfolder**. I have already tried the obvious which does not work

```
go.setImageUri("assets://MyFolder/Image2.jpg")"
```

Thanks

Comment: 'So, if I do `go.setImageUri("assets://Image3.jpg");` it works" -- `assets://` is not a valid scheme on Android, AFAIK. You are welcome to try `file:///android_asset/Image3.jpg` and `file:///android_asset/MyFolder/Image2.jpg`, though I don't know if `ImageView` will support that either. `file:///android_asset/` works with `WebView`, though.

Comment: Hi, I have tried   go.setImageUri("file:///android_asset/MyFolder/Image2.jpg") but still does not work. NOTE: I have no trouble displaying Image3.jpg, it is the images under the MyFolder that i am not able to display. Thanks

Comment: A GeoObject: http://beyondar.github.io/beyondar/doxygen/dc/dda/classcom_1_1beyondar_1_1android_1_1world_1_1_beyondar_object.html#af1533d1207a3ac4c16180e91f0b108d9